# Help with a difficult expected runtime recurrence

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, randomized-algorithms

I developed an algorithm and have a recurrence for its runtime; I want to show the expected runtime is $O(\sqrt{n})$.

At each iteration $i$, I have a random variable $k_i$ that is equal to the number of heads after flipping $\frac{n}{2^i}$ coins minus $\frac{n}{2^{i+1}}$ (i.e. a binomial distribution centered at 0 with width $\frac{n}{2^i}$). The runtime of my algorithm is then given by the following recurrence:

$$B(0) = 0$$
$$B(i) = \max\{B(i-1)+k_i, 0\}$$

When $B(i)$ is large, the negative and positive $k_i$ can cancel each other out, so intuitively one should be able to come up with a pretty good bound on $\mathbb{E}[B(n)]$, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @dw B(i-1) can be less than B(i) because this is actually not the runtime but just the term of the total runtime I can't bound. You are wrong that it's just a sum: when B(i-1) is small, the binomial distribution gets the left tail cut off. Since B(i-1) depends on previous values of k, the distributions are very much *not* independent.

Comment: OK, so this is a one-dimensional [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) with a boundary at the origin.  There's lots of theory on such random walks.  Perhaps some of it may be helpful for this problem?

Comment: @D.W. Yes, except the step size is binomially distributed. All the random walk theory I've ever seen has been with uniformly distributed step size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll have $B(i) = O(\sqrt{n})$ (with very high probability).

Note that $k_i$ is binomially distributed, so it is approximately Gaussian.  It has mean $0$ and standard deviation

$$\sigma_i = \sqrt{n} \times 2^{-i/2 - 1}.$$

The probability that $k_i$ is more than, say, 10 standard deviations above the mean is incredibly small.  We'll define the event $\textsf{BAD}_i$ to be true if $k_i \ge 10 \sigma_i$, and we'll define the event $\textsf{BAD}$ to hold if there exists $i$ such that $\textsf{BAD}_i$ holds, i.e.,

$$\textsf{BAD} = \textsf{BAD}_1 \lor \dots \lor \textsf{BAD}_m.$$

By a union bound, we have

$$\Pr[\textsf{BAD}] \le \sum_i \Pr[\textsf{BAD}_i],$$

which is still very small.  Moreover, if $\textsf{BAD}$ does *not* happen, then we have

$$B(m) \le \sum_i 10 \sigma_i = 10 \sqrt{n}/2 \sum_i {1 \over \sqrt{2}^i} \le 10 \sqrt{n}/2 \times 3.5 = O(\sqrt{n}).$$

In other words, there is a constant $c$ such that $B(m) \le c \times \sqrt{n}$ with overwhelmingly high probability.

(I've shamelessly handwaved and glossed over details all over the place to present the intuition in a clean way, but even correcting for them isn't going to change the bottom-line answer.)

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: wait, hold up... all this shows is that $\mathbb{E}[B(n)] = (1-p)O(\sqrt{n}) + pO(n)$ for some small *constant* $p$. So this would still be $O(n)$. Is there any way to get $p = O(1/\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: @RenéG, I *think* $p$ can be driven to be arbitrarily, exponentially small (by increasing the number "10" as needed), and this will only increase $c$ by a small amount ($\log (1/p)$ or less).  I realize this is all handwaving, so you should check my reasoning.  E.g., it's probably worth working out the details more formally/carefully.

Comment: Hm... what I really need to do is compute the expected value of $k_i$, which I think should be something like $\sqrt{n}/2^i$. Then there's no problem, just use linearity of expectation. Do you have any idea how the expected value of $k_i$ might be calculated?

Comment: Because if there's a $\log(1/p)$ factor, that would give me $O(\sqrt{n}\log{n})$, which I can already get using the a different algorithm.

Comment: Ah, found it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution. Just divide by 2.

Comment: @RenéG, the expected value of $k_i$ is 0 (as I say in my answer), as can be readily observed by computing the expected value of a binomial distribution.  However, this doesn't help you.  In particular, you can't just use linearity of expectation, as the $\max$ messes things up.  As far as the difference between $O(\sqrt{n})$ vs $O(\sqrt{n} \log n)$, I agree that my answer is not sensitive enough to prove that the right upper bound is the former rather than the latter.  Shall I delete this answer?

Comment: Oh ya expected value of $k_i$ is 0, of course... I meant something else, basically I found a way to write the expected runtime as a sum of a bunch of random variables with expected value $O(\sqrt{n}/2^{i/2})$ (they look like $B(1)$). What I did is the following: Define $C(i) = C(i-1) + |k_i|$. Clearly $B(i) \leq C(i)$. By linearity of expectation, $E[C(n)] = \sum_i E[|k_i|]$. By that wikipedia link, $E[|k_i|] = c\sqrt{n}/2^{i/2}$ for some constant $c$. So the sum is $O(\sqrt{n})$. Is this correct? If so, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @RenéG, very nice.  That looks good to me, and is much cleaner than my answer.  Yes, please post it, and I will delete my answer.